# Installing a unzipped module

Tags: module, prestashop

I've recently bought a theme for a different store, which came with a testimonial module. I'd like to use the same module in my other store.

Is there a way to install a unzipped theme?

If I just paste the files in my modules folder it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full module's package you can just copy it to the folder *dir*/modules/ and find it within your admin panel. But if you have the only part from the theme override folder you cannot use it. But I think that the first case is more probable, so just ensure that you have copied all files and kept the module structure correctly